# When does the next year become available as a start date in LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

I got accepted to study a degree next year, and wanted to add it to LinkedIn and Facebook, but I cannot set the start date to next year on LinkedIn.

On Facebook it is fine, you can add things to start on next year, but not on LinkedIn.

When does the next year (in this case, 2015) become available? Is it only once the year starts?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that LinkedIn is for recording what you HAVE done, not what you PLAN to do.

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ LinkedIn is a network for professionals to connect, I think it to be rather pertinent to any future employer whether or not his employees are aware of something that would either greatly enhance their knowledge of what they work with, or have a dire impact time-wise on their weekly schedule. Let alone both! - Regardless, I do agree that it is likely they only cater for the past, and not the immediate future as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - the year begins on day 1 of the actual year. In the meantime, you can add information in your Summary as to your future plans, so that others can see the career direction you are taking and courses you are planning to study. Then, when Jan 1 2015 gets here, you can transfer the information to your Education section, or even to your headline to announce your new goals.

Feel free to connect with me for additional help: www.linkedin.com/in/victoriaipri